# How to copy one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to copy the contents of table1 into table2, but it's not a straight copy, as table2 contains more columns than table 1. The structure is similar to this:

Table1
{
    column2
    column4
    column6
}

Table2
{
    column1
    column2
    column3
    column4
    column5
    column6
}

What I want to do is add every row from table1 to table2, and set default values for the missing columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do an

```
INSERT INTO xxx
SELECT yyy
```

And in the select clause, put default values.

```
INSERT INTO Table2(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
SELECT 'horse', column2, 2, column4, 'what ever I want', column6 
FROM Table1
```

So int Table2, all column1 will have 'horse' value.
All column3 will have 2.
Etc.

Comment: I didn't realise you could include values in the same select statement like that. Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `INSERT..INTO SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column2, column4, column6)
SELECT column2, column4, column6
FROM table1
```

so in this case, columns: `column1`, `column2`, `column3` will have null values. or whatever default you have set.

Comment: There are no default values set for table2. Is it possible to insert default values for the new columns as part of the single Insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

Not great at SQL but something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] (column2, column4, column6) SELECT (column1, column2, column3) FROM [Table2]
```

Hope this helps. Link that may be useful, http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLSelectInsert.aspx

*vote me I need points* :P

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
INSERT INTO 
    Table2  (
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    column5,
    column6,
        )
SELECT 
    'StaticValue1',
    column2,
    'StaticValue2'
    column4,
    'StaticValue3'
    column6,
FROM 
    Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy a full table into a new table:

```
SELECT * INTO table2 FROM table1;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

To copy a table into an existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: OP said the columns on the tables aren't one-to-one. I can't remember off-hand, but every other answer here specifies column names (presumably for this reason).

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into TABLE2
select null colum1, column2,null colum3,column4,null colum5,column6
from((
Select  TABLE1.column2, TABLE1.column4, TABLE1.column6
from TABLE1, TABLE2
where TABLE1.primarykey=TABLE2.primarykey))
```